# Print dialog window in electron

Tags: node.js, printing, electron

I want to print Docx files that users have created using a docx-templater. I found this library but it only supports pdf HTML and png: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-print-dialog.

```js
ipcMain.on('create:card:A', async function(e, jsonData){
      var files = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'files.json'), {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}));
      var userFile;
      files.forEach(function(file){
        if(file.name_and_surname == data){
          userFile = file;
        }
      })
      var template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'docx', 'Card.docx'))
      var buffer = await createReport({
        template,
        data: {
          sendData: [
            userFile.register_nr,
            userFile.name_and_surname,
            userFile.ID,
            getAge(userFile.ID),
          ]
        }
      })
      var tempFileId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
      fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'temp', 'docx', tempFileId + userFile.name_and_surname + '.docx'), buffer);
      //Here I want to print the document above 
    })
  })
```

Comment: @KJ That actually didn't help

Comment: yeah, sorry
I'll edit my post

Comment: @KJ I think it's better now

Comment: How viable is it to have the docx file converted to a PDF for printing?

Comment: @Stephen idk but I haven't any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

As docx is a proprietary Microsoft format, I see only two options here:

1. Convert docx to pdf, then print. You can try [OfficeToPdf](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF), a command line utility that converts Microsoft Office 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016 documents from their native format into PDF using Office's in-built PDF export features.
2. Use a cmd command to print pdf using Word. You can write needed commands in `.bat` file, or just execute needed command via command line. Example: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe" "D:/new/test.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mfileexit` (notice the Office version here)
   See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/995661/1119407).

An example to execute an external file:

```
import child_process from 'child_process'
const execFile = util.promisify(child_process.execFile);

let execResult = await mainModule.execFile(fileString, [
    inputPath,
    outputPath,
  ]);
```

For sure, you also can use an external web service to convert office formats to pdf. Example: [anyconv.com](https://anyconv.com/docx-to-html-converter/)